# Ruby gem version compatibility issues

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to use Ruby with MySql and two more gems, composite_primary_keys and ActiveRecord, however, I am seeing version compatibility issues. Following are the details of the system and tools versions:

```
OS: CentOS 4.9
gcc: 3.4.6

mysql: mysql  Ver 14.7 Distrib 4.1.22, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 4.3
ruby: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]
```

Gems versions:

```
mysql: 2.8.1
composite_primary_keys: 4.1.1
activerecord: 3.1.3
```

Is there any documentation that shows a version compatibility chart or something for gems?

Comment: maybe you should use `mysql2` instead of `mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gems has the `gem dependency` command, which shows what a particular gem expects:

```
gem depend mysql activerecord composite_primary_keys
Gem activerecord-3.1.3
  activemodel (= 3.1.3)
  activesupport (= 3.1.3)
  arel (~> 2.2.1)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)

Gem composite_primary_keys-4.1.1
  activerecord (~> 3.1)

Gem mysql-2.8.1
  hoe (>= 2.3.3, development)
  rake-compiler (~> 0.5, development)
```

You can use `gem dependency` by itself to see all dependencies of all gems if you want to wade through the list.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a documentation because the gem themselves declare which versions of the required gems are compatible with them. They may be wrong but so is any kind of documentation, implicit or explicit.

Anyway, which kind of problem do you have? It would be simpler if you report your issue to the gem authors or you post a question here so that other people can help you solve it or work around it.